# Как передать объект с выпадающего списка в другой объект в Thymeleaf через контроллер?

Tags: java, html5, spring, thymeleaf

Не могу никак понять как передать объект в поле объекта через выпадающий список.

Ошибка выходит такая: .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errorsField error in object 'receipt' on field 'supplier': rejected value [LegalEntity(id=3, name=Name, address=address, inn=456686901)];

**html файл**

```
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/receipts}" th:object="${receipt}">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Добавление приходной накладной</legend>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="number">Номер: </label></td>
                <td><label for="date">Дата: </label></td>
                <td><label for="total">Сумма: </label></td>
                <td><label for="supplier">Поставщик: </label></td>
                <td><label for="stock">Склад: </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input th:field="*{number}" type="text" id="number"></td>
                <td><input th:field="*{date}" type="date" id="date"></td>
                <td><input th:field="*{total}" type="text" id="total"></td>

                <td><select id="supplier" th:field="*{supplier}">
                    <option th:each="supplier : ${suppliers}"
                            th:value="${supplier}"
                            th:text="${supplier}">
                    </option>

                </select></td>
                <td><select id="stock" name="stock">
                    <option th:each="stock : ${stocks}"
                            th:value="${stock}"
                            th:text="${stock.getName()}">
                    </option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="tm-user-menu tm-user-menu_">
            <a th:href="@{/receipts}" rel="nofollow"
               class="tm-user-menu tm-user-menu_">Закрыть</a>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Метод контроллера**

```
@PostMapping()
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("receipt") Receipt receipt) {
        dao.save(receipt);
        return "redirect:/receipts";
    }
```

**Модель**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "receipts")
public class Receipt {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "receipt_id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String number;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private LegalEntity supplier;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Stock stock;

    @NotNull
    private float total;

    //private List<ReceiptDetail> details;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы сохранялся объект внутрь модели? Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Получилось так.

```
<td>
                    <select th:field="*{supplier}" id="supplier">
                        <option th:each="supplier : ${suppliers}"
                                th:value="${supplier.getId()}"
                                th:name="${supplier}"
                                th:text="${supplier.getName()}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
```